# laravel 5 showing internal error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have laravel 5 app working quite well on local server but as I transfer its all files to my server in directory (not in root) and accessing it like http://example.com/directory/public/ its showing "500 Internal Server Error". I have searched on Stack Overflow and found it could be error with `.htaccess`.

I tried adding `Rewritebase /` and `Options All` but nothing worked. Tried `.htaccess` code provided in Laravel docs but it didn't work.

Storage directory is set to 0777 and Laravel log file is set to 0666. Most files are set to 0664 and 0666. Deleting `.htaccess` file from `public` folder also shows same error.

I have just FTP'd the files of Laravel app from local to live server.

Comment: Have you checked your php/apache/laravel error logs? 500 errors cover a huge range of possibilities and any solution is just a stab in the dark without logs. Have you migrated your database, installed with composer, etc? What steps specifically have you taken to install laravel?

Comment: I have just transfered my all files from xampp to my server and import database schema and then changed env values in .env file

Comment: No error log files generated on server and no new log in framework log file

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared hosting then move all the files and folders from public to the root directory and change the paths in the **index.php** file accordingly. And either rename the public folder or delete it.

I think you cannot access public folder like you are accessing it even on your local machine. You first run the server then access it with the directory name. But if you don't want to run the server then do what I have mentioned in the first paragraph. That will also work on your live server. Access it with the address `http://example.com/directory`

Comment: I did as u said in first paragraph but still same error.